# Connect WalletConnect with html application

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, web3js, wallet-connect, web3modal

I need to connect WalletConnect Web3Modal with html application.

I'm following the documentation step by step: https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/web3modal/html-js/installation.

But server returns error.

What is the way to resolve this issue?

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

It's my code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WC</title>
    <script type="module" >
      import { EthereumClient, w3mConnectors, w3mProvider } from './node_modules/@web3modal/ethereum'
      import { Web3Modal } from './node_modules/@web3modal/html'
      import { configureChains, createClient } from './node_modules/@wagmi/core'
      import { arbitrum, mainnet, polygon } from './node_modules/@wagmi/core/chains'

      const chains = [arbitrum, mainnet, polygon]
      const projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID'

      const { provider } = configureChains(chains, [w3mProvider({ projectId })])
      const wagmiClient = createClient({
        autoConnect: true,
        connectors: w3mConnectors({ projectId, version: 1, chains }),
        provider
      })
      const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiClient, chains)
      const web3modal = new Web3Modal({ projectId }, ethereumClient)
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <w3m-core-button></w3m-core-button>
  </body>

</html>
```

I also tried running WalletConnect on localhost with reactjs and everything is fine, but I need to integrate it with the html application.

Answer (score 0):

Add the wrapper for page with id "app"

```html
 <div id="app">
    <w3m-core-button></w3m-core-button>
  </div>
```